# How I can make users authentication same on www.domain.com and domain.com

Tags: authentication

I am facing a issue, I have implemented User authentication using Node.Js and Passport.js.

The issue is when I am reaching out using eg:- domain.com it successfully logged me in but when i visit same website on [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) it is not preserving the authentication that was done using domain.com.

How I can preserve the user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Alternative to it is we can redirect all users coming on non-www domain to www domain

---

```
app.get("/*", function (req, res, next) {
  var protocol = "https://",
    host = req.headers.host,
    href;

  // if www. present, nothing to do here
  if (/^www\./i.test(host)) {
    next();
    return;
  }

  // Add www.
  host = host.replace("", "www.");
  href = protocol + host + req.url;
  console.log(href);
  res.statusCode = 301;
  res.setHeader("Location", href);
  res.write("Redirecting to " + host + req.url + "");
  res.end();
});
```